# how to connect TCP Socket server client with authentication in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a java and .Net solution, but now i need to implement in Dart  please help me out.

This is may java source

```
private Handler handler;
private int iCounter =1;
public StartQuickClient(int InstanceId)
{
    try
    {
        handler = MarketData.GetInstance();
        handler.setEventHandler(this);
        handler.setAddress("122.184.137.44");
        handler.setPort(9898);
        handler.setUserCredentials("PREM", "xxxxx");

        if (handler.connect())
        {
            System.out.println("Connect initiated "+ InstanceId);

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Connect failed ");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int InstanceId = rnd.nextInt(9999);
    StartQuickClient startQuickClient = new StartQuickClient(InstanceId);
}
```

This is the connect method:

```
public boolean connect() 
{

    try {
        if (quickEvent == null) {
            throw new Exception("No event handler is set, will not initiate the connection");
        }
        if (configuration.SERVER_ADDRESS == null) {
            throw new Exception("Blank Server Address");
        }
        if (configuration.SERVER_PORT <= 0) {
            throw new Exception("Blank Server Port");
        }
        tcpConnection = new TcpConnection(this, configuration);
        if (isNewVersionAuthentication) {
            tcpConnection.enableNewversionAuthentication();
        }
        tcpConnection.connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        mLog.error("No event handler is set and Blank Server Address,Port will not initiate the connection :" + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

please help me out if any one knows, i am new for dart,need any plug or how to do

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you work through a Dart tutorial, read API documentation, created some initial code to build upon? Or are you just hoping that somebody will take your Java code and rewrite it in Dart for you?

Comment: already i have a code to connecting server by using TCP Socket, but how to connect with  Authentication,thats what my requirement, i checked tutorials but i didn't get solution